# NodeJS - use remote module?

Tags: module, node.js, external

I'm working with node and would like to include a module stored on a remote server in my app.

I.E. I'd like to do something along these lines (which does not work as is):

var remoteMod = require('http:// ... *url to my remote module* ... ');

As a workaround I'd be happy with just grabbing the contents of the remote file and parsing out what I need if that's easier - though I haven't had much luck with that either. I have a feeling I'm missing something basic here (as I'm a relative beginner with node), but couldn't turn up anything after scouring the docs.

EDIT:

I own both local and remote servers so I'm not concerned with security issues here.

If I'm just going to grab the file contents I'd like to do so this synchronously. Using require('http').get can get me the file, but working from within the callback is not optimal for what I'm trying to do. I'd really be looking for something akin to php's fopen function - if that's even doable with node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab remote file just via http
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/http.html#http.get

```
require('http').get({host: 'www.example.com', path: '/mystaticfile.txt'}, function(res) {
 //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know of a way I could get the file's contents synchronously?

Comment: Via http? I don't think so. You can put rest of your code into closure function instead.

Comment: try this instead of the built in http module. I can't vouch for it, but it looks like what you need https://github.com/dhruvbird/http-sync

Also, you're probably better off doing it async.

Answer (score 5):

Running code loaded from another server is very dangerous. What if someone can modify this code? This person would be able to run every code he wants on your server.

Comment: Thanks - I understand the dangers here, as it happens though I own the remote server as well.

Comment: Maybe you should then mount the folder that contains your module through sftp into your filesystem ;) This would be much more secure & handy!

Comment: I should give you a little more insight into what I'm trying to do... I want to get at some data stored in the remote DB, but I also want that data to get processed by (non-js) scripts that already live on that server (I.E. I don't want to have two copies of those scripts in different languages that need to be maintained). It would be nice if I could make a web request to the remote server that loads up some data, processes it, then builds and sends back my custom module file. Just mounting the file locally won't be much help as I need the remote server to build it first for each web request.

Comment: Ok, I think this will not be possible the synchronus way (as mentioned in your comment to emmerman´s answer).